# How to change the text of the ViewCubeUI in Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

For a marine application, I'd like to change the text of the ViewCubeUI from

- left -> port
- right -> starboard
- front -> bow
- back -> stern

[image]

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ViewCubeUi/).
Currently, it's not possible to change the text.